# Compare two dates fetched from a sql table in java

Tags: java, date, jdbc

I want to compare two dates fetched from a SQL query to know which one is greater. Date format in the sql is

```
2018-11-22 11:12:38.291647
```

I tried using

```
java.util.Date sqlDate=new java.util.Date(resultset.getDate().getTime());
```

But it keeps on asking to change the datatype to int.

I also tried using

```
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date d=df.format(/*date String*/);
```

But this also does not work. it keeps on asking to change the datatype of d to String.

Comment: In the second attempt you may correct the date format "yyyy-MM-dd" to the format of your sql date '2018-11-22 11:12:38.291647'. It could be "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS". Please confirm the format, I have not tested it.

Comment: You should use `ResultSet.getTimestamp()` rather than `getDate()`, e.g. `java.sql.Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp(1)` or even better `LocalDateTime ldt = resultSet.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class)`

Comment: Also: `date`  or `timestamp` values do not have "a format". Any format you see is applied when you print such a value.

Comment: What is your datatype in SQL? `timestamp`? It shouldn’t be `char` for a date-time column, that is, its format should be of no concern.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can order the result of a query in SQL with the `ORDER BY` command. If you want the "biggest" date, you should order the query descending: `ORDER BY DESC`.

This way you can get the biggest date from the `ResultSet` object holding the result of your query by simply extracting the first element.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert in `Date` objects:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss");
Date date = format.parse(yourDate);
```

and then compare them using [`Date.after`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) or [`Date.before`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date))

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

**This type of format** is comparable in java by comparing the strings, so you don't need any conversion:

```
String date1 = "2018-11-22 11:12:38.291647";
String date2 = "2018-11-23 10:11:00.090600";
int result = date1.compareTo(date2);

System.out.println(result);
```

will print

```
-1
```

because `date2` is "greater" than `date1`.
if `date1` is "greater" than `date2` the result is `1` and 
if `date1` is "equal" to `date2` the result is `0`

Answer (score 0):

## No “format” in database

> Date format in the sql is 2018-11-22 11:12:38.291647

No, it is not.

Date-time values stored in date-time types have no “format”. Formats are for strings. A database stores a date-time value by its own internally-defined data structure. The details of that data structure is none of our business.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Exchange date-time objects of a date-time class with a database for values stored in a date-time column.

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. No need to ever again use those terrible legacy classes such as `java.sql.Timestamp`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, and `java.util.Calendar`.

For a moment, in the database use a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

## `OffsetDateTime`

For such a column, pass a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object to your prepared statement. Usually best to work in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-11-22T11:12:38.291647Z" ) ;  // `Z` on the end means UTC. Pronounced “Zulu”.
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Compare

Compare `OffsetDateTime` objects using `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual`.

```
boolean aIsBeforeThanB = odtA.isBefore( odtB );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).